# data latitude, longitude of place didn't sent using ShareOpenGraphObject, Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Problem with Android SDK when sent place:location data.

3 Case Object already test,
- Object inheritance Place (place:location)
- Object inheritance Place + custom GeoPoint (place:location & nesty:location), i got message it's wrong, so I remove it.
- Object inheritance Object + custom GeoPoint (nesty:location)

i'm have an object inheritance with place object. And when using android SDK im trying to using opengraph to share an location (custom). I already tried to putString and putDouble property of 'place:location:latitude' and 'place:location:longitude', but it didnt appear on Object also the place are unknown. (throw to antarctica).

I'm trying to create new parameter GeoPoint and input it, 'nesty:location:latitude' and 'nesty:location:longitude' and it send. but when trying to display story with attachment as map, it didn't display the marker correctly (throw to antarctica, I means, nesty:location data already sent correctly but location i don't know still using place:location, like is it still same with/without new parameter) [Message from FB Team, don't use 2 GeoPoint in 1 object)

I'm trying to create new object with inheritance object (no-place), and create new parameter GeoPoint, 'nesty:location:latitude' and 'nesty:location:longitude', change attachment to layout map, highligh marker using nesty:location and in object explorer data nesty:location is correct, but the story didn't show as map. (like link stories), but I got the data, in parameter {"latitude":-7.2615318298,"longitude":112.7506713867,"altitude":0}

here last my code, for object inheritance place [1]

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "nest")
            .putString("og:title", nest.name)
            .putString("og:description", nest.desc)
            .putDouble("place:location:latitude", nest.lat)
            .putDouble("place:location:longitude", nest.lon)
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("nesty:nest")
            .putObject("nest", object)
            .build();

    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("nest")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

When posting, the data like title, desc already in, also with the story, but the location is not.

I'm also trying to using replace `putDouble` into `putString` also didn't work.
I'm also trying to divide the object like this too and didn't work,

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject location = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("location:latitude", nest.lat)
            .putString("location:longitude", nest.lon)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "nest")
            .putString("og:title", nest.name)
            .putString("og:description", nest.desc)
            .putString("place:location", location)
            .build();
```

here last my code, for object inheritance object (no-place default geopoint), the data sent but the stories didn't appear as map (already set highligh to nesty:location) [3]

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "nest")
            .putString("og:title", nest.name)
            .putString("og:description", nest.desc)
            .putDouble("nesty:location:latitude", nest.lat)
            .putDouble("nesty:location:longitude", nest.lon)
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("nesty:nest")
            .putObject("nest", object)
            .build();

    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("nest")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

Note: I already submit into fb https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/717172958383981 still in discuss.

Comment: `I'm trying to create new parameter GeoPoint and input it, 'app:location:latitude' and 'app:location:longitude' and it send. but when trying to display story with attachment as map, it didn't display the marker correctly (throw to antarctica).` this means you already got place to work, right? but it's set in the wrong place? I would revise your coordinates to see what's going on.

Comment: @ifaour I notice custom parameter got it right, {"latitude":-7.2615318298,"longitude":112.7506713867,"altitude":0} but the marker still throw using place:location (whatever I change highligh marker to place:location or nesty:location is same), also I got notice from fb team, don't make 2 GeoPoint, So i remove it and create 2 object, One with inheritance place, One with inheritance object + geopoint. still not working. btw I update the case.